# Calling a ruby method once when the class is defined

Tags: ruby, class

Say I have multiple child classes that inherit from a common parent.

I want to use `define_method` to programmatically define some methods on each child. But the list of methods to define *is different for each child)*.

So I implemented something as below -

```
class Parent
  def define_some_methods!
    self.class::MY_METHODS.each do |m|
      proc = Proc.new { "You called method #{m}" }
      self.class.send(:define_method, m, &proc)
    end
  end
end

class ChildOne < Parent
  MY_METHODS = [:foo, :bar]

  def initialize
    define_some_methods!
  end
end

class ChildTwo < Parent
  MY_METHODS = [:alpha, :bravo]

  def initialize
    define_some_methods!
  end
end

ChildOne.new.foo    #=> "You called method foo"
ChildTwo.new.alpha  #=> "You called method alpha"
```

This works fine, but it calls `define_some_methods` each time a new class is instantiated. That constantly redefines the same methods over and over at the class level.

Is there a way to do this **once** when the initial class is defined?

I tried something like -

```
class ChildTwo < Parent
  MY_METHODS = [:alpha, :bravo]

  define_some_methods!
end
```

But it errors with

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `define_some_methods!' for ChildTwo:Class
Did you mean?  define_method
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need metaprogramming in this case? Can you just define the method in Parent with an extra param for method name?

If Parent can be a module, then we can solve it this way:

```
module Parent
  def self.module(*methods)
    Module.new do |_mod|
      methods.each do |method|
        define_method(method) { "You called method #{method}" }
      end
    end
  end
end

class ChildOne
  include Parent.module(:foo, :bar)
end

class ChildTwo
  include Parent.module(:alpha, :bravo)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined an instance method for a parent, but you need a class method, like this:

```
class Parent
  def self.define_some_methods!
    self::MY_METHODS.each do |m|
      proc = Proc.new { "You called method #{m}" }
      send(:define_method, m, &proc)
    end
  end
end
```